# Allocating an Array in Memory Manager

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I want to successfully allocate an Array in my Memory Manager. I am having a hard time getting the data setup successfully in my Heap. I don't know how to instantiate the elements of the array, and then set the pointer that is passed in to that Array. *Any help would be greatly appreciated.* **=)**

Basically to sum it up, I want to write my own new[#] function using my own Heap block instead of the normal heap. Don't even want to think about what would be required for a dynamic array. **o.O**

```
// Parameter 1: Pointer that you want to pointer to the Array.
// Parameter 2: Amount of Array Elements requested.
// Return: true if Allocation was successful, false if it failed.
template <typename T>
bool AllocateArray(T*& data, unsigned int count)
{
    if((m_Heap.m_Pool == nullptr) || count <= 0)
        return false;

    unsigned int allocSize = sizeof(T)*count;
    // If we have an array, pad an extra 16 bytes so that it will start the data on a 16 byte boundary and have room to store
    // the number of items allocated within this pad space, and the size of the original data type so in a delete call we can move
    // the pointer by the appropriate size and call a destructor(potentially a base class destructor) on each element in the array
    allocSize += 16;

    unsigned int* mem = (unsigned int*)(m_Heap.Allocate(allocSize));
    if(!mem)
    {
        return false;
    }

    mem[2] = count;
    mem[3] = sizeof(T);

    T* iter = (T*)(&(mem[4]));
    data = iter;
    iter++;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i,++iter)
    {
        // I have tried a bunch of stuff, not sure what to do.  :(
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Heap Allocate function:**

```
void* Heap::Allocate(unsigned int allocSize)
{
Header* HeadPtr = FindBlock(allocSize);
Footer* FootPtr = (Footer*)HeadPtr;
FootPtr = (Footer*)((char*)FootPtr + (HeadPtr->size + sizeof(Header)));

// Right Split Free Memory if there is enough to make another block.
if((HeadPtr->size - allocSize) >= MINBLOCKSIZE)
{           
    // Create the Header for the Allocated Block and Update it's Footer
    Header* NewHead = (Header*)FootPtr;
    NewHead = (Header*)((char*)NewHead - (allocSize + sizeof(Header)));
    NewHead->size = allocSize;
    NewHead->next = NewHead;
    NewHead->prev = NewHead;
    FootPtr->size = NewHead->size;

    // Create the Footer for the remaining Free Block and update it's size
    Footer* NewFoot = (Footer*)NewHead;
    NewFoot = (Footer*)((char*)NewFoot - sizeof(Footer));
    HeadPtr->size -= (allocSize + HEADANDFOOTSIZE);
    NewFoot->size = HeadPtr->size;

    // Turn new Header and Old Footer High Bits On
    (NewHead->size |= (1 << 31)); 
    (FootPtr->size |= (1 << 31));

    // Return actual allocated memory's location
    void* MemAddress = NewHead;
    MemAddress = ((char*)MemAddress + sizeof(Header));

    m_PoolSizeTotal = HeadPtr->size;
    return MemAddress;
}
else
{
    // Updating descriptors
    HeadPtr->prev->next = HeadPtr->next;
    HeadPtr->next->prev = HeadPtr->prev;
    HeadPtr->next = NULL;
    HeadPtr->prev = NULL;

    // Turning Header and Footer High Bits On
    (HeadPtr->size |= (1 << 31)); 
    (FootPtr->size |= (1 << 31));

    // Return actual allocated memory's location
    void* MemAddress = HeadPtr;
    MemAddress = ((char*)MemAddress + sizeof(Header));

    m_PoolSizeTotal = HeadPtr->size;
    return MemAddress;
}
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int* TestArray;

MemoryManager::GetInstance()->CreateHeap(1);  // Allocates 1MB

MemoryManager::GetInstance()->AllocateArray(TestArray, 3);

MemoryManager::GetInstance()->DeallocateArray(TestArray);

MemoryManager::GetInstance()->DestroyHeap();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "initialize the elements of the array" -- do you want them zero'd, or set some default value?

Comment: Dare I ask: 1) Why are you reinventing the wheel? 2)Why are you not overloading new? 3)You do realize this is highly platform specific? If you were doing this in windows lets say, you would be looking at heapAlloc, in linux at mmap or similar. 4)Are you trying to make sure that contiguous memory is used?

Comment: @hazydev  Yes, I wanted to set them to their default values as specified by their constructors.


I am attempting to have a contiguous and pre-allocated block of memory to use for our game. Instead of us calling and using new, we could use my Allocate function for my Heap.
We are programming in a Win32 application, so I'm not worried about writing code for platform independent code, I just want to make sure it works for our game at the moment. We are using Visual Studio 2012 for an IDE.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for inplace new -- I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as these two specific points:

1. Instantiate the elements of the array
2. Set the pointer that is passed in to that Array.

For (1): there is no definitive notion of "initializing" the elements of the array in C++. There are at least two reasonable behaviors, this depends on the semantics you want. The first is to simply zero the array (see memset). The other would be to call the default constructor for each element of the array -- I would not recommend this option as the default (zero argument) constructor may not exist.

EDIT: Example initialization using inplace-new

```
 for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    new (&arr[i]) T();
```

For (2): It is not exactly clear what you mean by "and then set the pointer that is passed in to that Array." You could "set" the memory returned as `data = static_cast<T*>(&mem[4])`, which you already do.

A few other words of cautioning (having written my own memory managers), be very careful about byte alignment (reinterpret_cast(mem) % 16); you'll want to ensure you are returning points that are word (or even 16 byte) aligned. Also, I would recommend using inttypes.h to explicitly use uint64_t to be explicit about sizing -- current it looks like this allocator will break for >4GB allocations.

EDIT:
Speaking from experiment -- writing a memory allocator is a very difficult thing to do, and it is even more painful to debug. As commenters have stated, a memory allocator is specific to the kernel -- so information about your platform would be very helpful.